# add tab in jtabbedPane like google chrome

Tags: java, swing, google-chrome, jtabbedpane

Hello I need to make a tab panel like google chrome. You press another tab , and chrome put the tab. I have this.
[image: first screen]

but when I press the tab with symbol "+" , this is the effect :
[image: second screen]

I thought exchange the position with symbol "+" for the position on the new tab, but I can't do it. I have problems. Really I want to do like navigator chrome , that effect. Thanks. Here I have the code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
    VentanaPrincipalFrame ventana = new     VentanaPrincipalFrame();
                ventana.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

Principal Frame:

```
public class VentanaPrincipalFrame extends JFrame {

private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

private JPanel panelAdd;


public VentanaPrincipalFrame() {

    initFrame();

    panelAdd = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

    tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        int i = 1;

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

            JTabbedPane tab = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();

            if( tab.getSelectedIndex() == tabbedPane.getTabCount()-1 && tabbedPane.getTabCount() > 1){
                i++;
                addPestana("Tab"+i);
                //mensaje("Hola soy el ultimo");
            }

        }
    });


    getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    tabbedPane.addTab("New tab", new PanelDinamicoPanel());
    tabbedPane.addTab( "+", panelAdd );

}

public void addPestana(String titulo){

    tabbedPane.addTab( titulo , new PanelDinamicoPanel() );

}



private void initFrame() {

    setTitle("Principal");
    setSize(400,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}



}
```

My custom tab:

```
public class PanelDinamicoPanel extends JPanel{

private JTextField textField;


public PanelDinamicoPanel() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel botonesPanel = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout flowLayout_1 = (FlowLayout) botonesPanel.getLayout();
    flowLayout_1.setAlignment(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
    add(botonesPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) panel.getLayout();
    flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
    botonesPanel.add(panel);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    panel.add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");
    panel.add(btnNewButton_1);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    add(panel_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    GridBagLayout gbl_panel_1 = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panel_1.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
    gbl_panel_1.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
    gbl_panel_1.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_panel_1.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    panel_1.setLayout(gbl_panel_1);

    JLabel lblNombre = new JLabel("Name");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNombre = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblNombre.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_lblNombre.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_lblNombre.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblNombre.gridy = 0;
    panel_1.add(lblNombre, gbc_lblNombre);

    textField = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textField.gridy = 0;
    panel_1.add(textField, gbc_textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

}



}
```

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: The change event is being trigger because of change in the state of the tabs model, namely the selected tab, so when the stateChanged method is called, the selected tab is now the "+" tab...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, instead of "adding" a tab, you need to "insert" one, something like...

```
 Component tabComp = ...
 tab.insertTab("Title", null, tabComp, null, index);
```

For example, where `index` is the location where you want the new tab to be added.  If you just want to maintain the "+" at the end, the something like `tab.getTabCount() - 1` should do the trick

If you want to add the tab next to the last active tab, then you need to get a little more adventurous...

The problem is, when the `stateChanged` event is triggered, the selection has already changed, so doing `tab.getSelectedIndex()` will always return the "+" tab.

What you need to know is the tab that was selected BEFORE it.

What you could do is inspect the selected tab when the state changed, if it's not the "+" tab, you will want to record the selected index value.

When the "+" tab becomes active, you would simply use the "last selected index" value your have being tracking as a base for inserting the new tab...

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TestTabSelection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTabSelection();
    }

    public TestTabSelection() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                final JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
                tab.addTab("A", new JPanel());
                tab.addTab("+", new JPanel());
                tab.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    private int lastSelected;
                    private boolean ignore = false;

                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        if (!ignore) {
                            ignore = true;
                            try {
                                int selected = tab.getSelectedIndex();
                                String title = tab.getTitleAt(selected);
                                if ("+".equals(title)) {
                                    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
                                    tab.insertTab("Tab" + (tab.getTabCount() - 1), null, pane, null, lastSelected + 1);
                                    tab.setSelectedComponent(pane);
                                } else {
                                    lastSelected = selected;
                                }
                            } finally {
                                ignore = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                final JButton btn = new JButton("Add");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println(tab.getTabCount());
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tab);
                frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you :

```
tab.setTabComponentAt(tab.getTabCount() - 1, new PanelDinamicoPanel());
tab.addTab("+", null);
```

Hope that helps, Salam

Comment: Sorry I did that in the fly :P I think the only problem is that the new tab don't have a title, well I'll make a real test for you!